# python selenium enter search query then wait

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys(search_query + Keys.ENTER)
actions.perform()
# code to wait until page loads
src = driver.page_source
```

How would I implement this? I'm trying to send keys to the search box, which i have, and then after the .perform I would like it to wait till the search results load, then get the source. Is that possible with selenium?

Trying to find a way better than `time.sleep(2)` Maybe something like `driver.wait_until_page_loads()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like it to wait till the search results load

What you are looking for is a `WebDriverWait` (aka an "Explicit Wait").

You want to choose a specific element that signifies the results are loaded and wait for that.  Suppose you are waiting for the presence of an element that can be located with the `id` of `mySearchResults`.  The code would look like this.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# create driver and execute search here

# now wait for the presence of the `mySearchResults` element.
# if it is not found within 10 secs, a `TimeOutException` is raised.
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "mySearchResults")))
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed :)